# startup script in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, batch-file

My application need to start when windows start. so i writed a batch file for running the application.

This is the code for writing the batch file path entry to registry.

```
private void RegisterInStartup(bool isChecked)
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    if (isChecked)
    {
        registryKey.SetValue("ApplicationName", Application.StartupPath+"\\autorun.bat");
    }
    else
    {
        registryKey.DeleteValue("ApplicationName");
    }
}
```

And this is my batch file code.

```
start File.exe
exit
```

When I restart my system the batch file is executing but the application File.exe is not executing.

Why this happening?

Comment: "Can anyone tell me why this happening?" We can guess, but what diagnostics have performed (eg. Process Monitor trace)? I would suspect a path issue, but need those diagnostics to confirm.

Comment: PS. Why not call the application (`file.exe`) directly from the `Run` key? PPS. That registry key relates to that user logging on, not system startup.

Comment: yes i know that registry key is for current user
i also tried to set the path directly to (file.exe) but i got a lot of errorlike

`See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error
no such table: t01_shedule`

actually the table is there when i run the file.exe by manually it is working perfectly

Comment: An exception means that `file.exe` *is* executing. So you need to detail that error message. Have you tried using the debugging tools for windows to capture a dump on exception?

Comment: You probably may see the Exception in the Application Event log.

Answer (score 1):

The batch file is not started from the directory where it exists. therefore File.exe will not be found. Replace batch with exe, or provide a full path to the exe as well.

Comment: Instead of 'start File.exe' use 'start "[Full Path Here]\File.exe'

Answer (score 0):

1. Test your batch file manually. Click on it. Does the application start?
2. Enter the path manually in the registry. Does the registry key work?
3. Export the registry key to a file. Delete the registry and and add it again with your  program and export it and compare the two files. If 1 and 2 where working, there must be a difference in the registry key, and with this way you will find the difference

Comment: When i run the batch file my application is working 
and also done step 2,3 no diffrence.